# Py2Neo: graph.cypher.execute()

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

are there any way to make this function more nice/readerble? (eg. format the string so i don't have "create .." + label + "...")

```
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph()

def create_node(label, properties):
    """Create a note with the label-type and some properties"""
    graph.cypher.execute("CREATE (p:" + label + " " + properties + ")")

create_node("Person", "{name: 'Alice', age: '22'}")
```

Comment: something like str.format() would be nice, but there are some problems when there are two sets of "{}" (one for cypher and one for .format()

Comment: Though I don't know py2neo, This might work `"CREATE (p: {} {} )".format(label , properties)`

Comment: Tried that, but Cypher complains when I do it like that.. :-( (Or maybe I just did it in a wrong way?) - But thanks for your answer.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about using py2neo's built-in methods? You would just do

```
from py2neo import Node
alice = Node("Person", name="Alice", age=22)
```

If you definitely want to use Cypher, it's going to be somewhat inelegant because you can't parameterize labels. I also suggest passing a Python dict as the properties instead of the string:

```
def create_node(label, properties):
    query = "CREATE (:{}".format(label) + " {properties})"
    params = dict(properties=properties)
    graph.cypher.execute(query, params)

create_node("Person", {"name":"Alice","age":22})
```

The reason that `"CREATE (:{} {})".format(label, properties)` doesn't work is because the dictionary's keys will be wrapped in quotes, which is invalid Cypher. For example:

```
>>> d = dict(name="Alice",age=22)
>>> label = "Person"
>>> "CREATE (:{} {})".format(label, properties)
"CREATE (:Person {'age': 22, 'name': 'Alice'})"
```

This will throw an error, because valid Cypher would be:

```
"CREATE (:Person {age: 22, name: 'Alice'})"
```

Comment: Woah! Great answer. But doesnt this have support for `?` like in Sqlite3 or even the other neo4j API?

Comment: The equivalent for `?` is parameters (curly braces in Cypher). See here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html. The second argument to `graph.cypher.execute` is a dictionary of parameter key-value pairs. See here: http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html. In your case, `{properties}` is a parameter and you're passing in a dictionary with a key `properties`.

Comment: Oh thanks. Hadn't used `py2neo`. More acquainted with the `neo4j` direct API

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! I went for Cypher, as I found it more intuitive. But might consider mixing it. :-)

Comment: I would suggest also using the `cypher_escape` function when embedding labels and relationship types: http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html#py2neo.cypher.cypher_escape